# C#: How do I get a button to call itself once when used on 3 other buttons

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I had already posted this question about a month ago but it got a lot of negative reviews because I had forgotten to post the code beforehand.

I am trying to get a temporary buff system to work in this game and what I want it to do is this. When the user clicks on the first button, it will open the buff panel and give the user a choice of how much ever buffs there are. Then the user can click on the buff they wish to have and it will change the first button's image to match the buff they clicked. Then the same idea will happen for the second and third button slots.

Currently, it is doing all that but when the second button is clicked, it will cast the picture on both first and second buttons. Then when the third button is clicked, it will cast the picture on all 3 buttons. From the code below, it seems that the reason is because the onClick is adding the listener each time the buff is clicked, so it is doing it multiple times. But I don't know how to change it so that it will only occur once. I would appreciate all the help I can get!

The code is listed below:

```
void Start(){
    buffSlot_1.GetComponent<Button>();
    buffSlot_1.onClick.AddListener(() => addBuff(buffSlot_1));

    buffSlot_2.GetComponent<Button>();
    buffSlot_2.onClick.AddListener(() => addBuff(buffSlot_2));

    buffSlot_3.GetComponent<Button>();
    buffSlot_3.onClick.AddListener(() => addBuff(buffSlot_3));
}

void addBuff(Button purchaseButton) {

    buffPanel.SetActive(true);

    damageBoostButton.GetComponent<Button>();
    damageBoostButton.onClick.AddListener(() => {
        if (coinCount >= 0) {
            Debug.Log("Gain a damage boost!");
            dmgBool = true;
            buffPanel.SetActive(false);
            purchaseButton.interactable = false;
            damageBoostButton.interactable = false;
            purchaseButton.image.sprite = damageBoostButton.image.sprite;
            coinCount -= 0;
        }
    });

    defenseBoostButton.GetComponent<Button>();
    defenseBoostButton.onClick.AddListener(() => {
        if (coinCount >= 0) {
            Debug.Log("Gain a defense boost!");
            defBool = true;
            buffPanel.SetActive(false);
            purchaseButton.interactable = false;
            defenseBoostButton.interactable = false;
            purchaseButton.image.sprite = defenseBoostButton.image.sprite;
            coinCount -= 0;
        }
    });

    critBoostButton.GetComponent<Button>();
    critBoostButton.onClick.AddListener(() => {
        if (coinCount >= 0) {
            Debug.Log("Crit Boost");
            critBool = true;
            buffPanel.SetActive(false);
            purchaseButton.interactable = false;
            critBoostButton.interactable = false;
            purchaseButton.image.sprite = critBoostButton.image.sprite;
            coinCount -= 0;
        }
    });

    hasteBoostButton.GetComponent<Button>();
    hasteBoostButton.onClick.AddListener(() => {
        if (coinCount >= 0) {
            Debug.Log("Haste Boost");
            hasteBool = true;
            buffPanel.SetActive(false);
            purchaseButton.interactable = false;
            hasteBoostButton.interactable = false;
            purchaseButton.image.sprite = hasteBoostButton.image.sprite;
            coinCount -= 0;
        }
    });

    iceSpikeButton.GetComponent<Button>();
    iceSpikeButton.onClick.AddListener(() => {
        if (coinCount >= 0) {
            Debug.Log("Increase Ice Spike");
            iceSpikeBool = true;
            buffPanel.SetActive(false);
            purchaseButton.interactable = false;
            iceSpikeButton.interactable = false;
            purchaseButton.image.sprite = iceSpikeButton.image.sprite;
            coinCount -= 0;
        }
    });

    iceWallButton.GetComponent<Button>();
    iceWallButton.onClick.AddListener(() => {
        if (coinCount >= 0) {
            Debug.Log("Increase Ice Wall");
            iceWallBool = true;
            buffPanel.SetActive(false);
            purchaseButton.interactable = false;
            iceWallButton.interactable = false;
            purchaseButton.image.sprite = iceWallButton.image.sprite;
            coinCount -= 0;
        }
    });

    healthRegenButton.GetComponent<Button>();
    healthRegenButton.onClick.AddListener(() => {
        if (coinCount >= 0) {
            Debug.Log("HPRegen Boost");
            hpRegenBool = true;
            buffPanel.SetActive(false);
            purchaseButton.interactable = false;
            healthRegenButton.interactable = false;
            purchaseButton.image.sprite = healthRegenButton.image.sprite;
            coinCount -= 0;
        }
    });
}
```

The coinCounts are set to 0 just for testing purposes.

Comment: Is this using Unity?  Might want to tag it as such.

Comment: Oh yes! It is Unity, thanks for reminding me! I will tag it now.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Unity, but it looks like you are attaching multiple event handlers to the buff buttons.  Each time you call `addBuff` you are adding another event handler to each button.  The previous handlers still hold references to the previous purchase buttons.

Comment: I understand that. I suppose that would be the issue to it, but I'm not sure how to go about fixing it. I don't want to constantly add listeners. I just want it to do a few commands when clicked. This is in a giant script that has over 600 lines. It holds almost every command in that one scene.

Comment: Why do you call `.GetComponent<Button>();` and not storing the result? It is completely unnecessary.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand. I've only started Unity/C# programming a couple of months ago and this is how I've dealt with buttons the entire time. Is there a way to store the result differently? I thought .GetComponent<Button>(); is how we initialize the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to finally get it to work the way I wanted to. It was simply to add a RemoveAllListeners on every button's onClick in the addBuff method before calling the addListener.

Therefore each button in the method will look like this:

```
   `damageBoostButton.onClick.RemoveAllListeners();
    damageBoostButton.onClick.AddListener(() => {
        if (coinCount >= 500) {
            Debug.Log("Gain a damage boost!");
            dmgBool = true;
            buffPanel.SetActive(false);
            purchaseButton.interactable = false;
            damageBoostButton.interactable = false;
            purchaseButton.image.sprite = damageBoostButton.image.sprite;
            coinCount -= 500;
        }
    });`
```

That way, before adding any listeners, it will delete all listeners currently operating then add new ones to the button.

Thanks for trying to help guys!